# Next production bundle in Cypress does not locate static files

Tags: next.js, cypress, next-i18next

I am using `next-i18next` for my translation.  Inside the `<rootDir>/public` dir are my translation *.json files.

```
"next": "^10.0.2",
"next-i18next": "^8.1.1",
```

My Cypress tests fail when running my production bundle, because the full text string is not found.  It only displays the value of the translation key: `t('someKey')`.

next-i18next.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en'],
  },
  localePath: path.resolve('./public/static/locales'),
};
```

next.config.js file:

```
const defaultConfig = {
  i18n,
  redirects: require('./next-redirects'),
}
```

_app.js:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
   /// snipped
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp);
```

page with error (not limited to just this single page)

```
export const SearchPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { t } = useTranslation('search'); 

  // snipped //

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{`${t('searchTitle')}`}</title>
        <meta
          property="og:title"
          content={`${t('searchTitle')}`}
          key="title"
        />
        <meta
          name="description"
          content={t('metaDescription')}
        />
      </Head>
      <ItemsContext.Provider
        value={{snipped}}>
         <Search />
      </ItemsContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

SearchPage.namespace = 'SearchPage';

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ locale }) => ({
  // exposes `_nextI18Next` as props which includes our namespaced files
  props: {
    ...await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common', 'search']),
  }
});

export default SearchPage;
```

Commands used:

```
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"cypress.test": "npx cypress run",
```

running yarn dev works fine as shown:
[image]

running `yarn build && yarn start && yarn cypress.test` will output this:
[image]

If I try to replicate the failure on my local machine with `yarn build` the translation is OK.

From the [nextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) on static file serving:

> Note: Only assets that are in the public directory at build time will be served by Next.js. Files added at runtime won't be available. We recommend using a third party service like AWS S3 for persistent file storage.

It appears that the serverSideTranslations function might be considered runtime - because my pages are not pre-built when related to dynamic path URLs.

Please advise on serverSideTranslations considered runtime vs buildtime?

Comment: yes @juliomalves, `getServerSideProps` is on each request on all page level components.

Comment: are you trying to explain it is a runtime function and therefore the assets are runtime too?

Comment: I'm just highlighting the fact that `serverSideTranslations` gets called on each request. Your translations live under the `/public` folder so those should be there at build-time and accessible. I don't have a solution but my guess would be that the issue is with Cypress rather than Next.js.

Comment: Gotcha...thanks.  what's super interesting is the bundle works fine when next app is deployed with Vercel.